# yandex-maps: ballonopen

Tags: yandex-maps-api, координаты

Всем привет.
При нажатии на обьект на карте (школа, больница) открывается балун и выбрасывается событие **ballonopen**. Как из этого события получить **координаты** обьекта?

Answer (score 0):

Координаты балуна возвращаются через [getPosition()](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/IPopup#getPosition). Но простой балун получает классические координаты. А балун, открытый на POI возвращает глобальные координаты, которые нужно преобразовывать через [fromGlobalPixels](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/IProjection#fromGlobalPixels).

Сами метки POI видны на достаточно крупных масштабах, потому можно использовать код примерно такого вида:

```
myMap.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
    var balloonPosition = myMap.balloon.getPosition()
    if (balloonPosition[1]>180) {
        var POIcoords = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(balloonPosition, myMap.getZoom());
        console.log(POIcoords) //координаты балуна на POI
    } else {
        console.log(balloonPosition) //координаты обычного балуна
    }
});
```